# Fetch inbox and outbox

Tags: android

I want to create a conversation window. So I need to fetch the inbox and the outbox.

How I do it now is:

Get the inbox and outbox messages ( from one thread ) and put them in a list then sort the list on date.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I think you can store each conversation in a DB table. One table per conversation. In this table there are three main columns: message, time, sender (me or not me). When you load conversation, you create sql query to load data from table sorted by time. And with sender value you can understand is this message yours or not. I think that I will do this in such a way. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you going to save conversation in local database you have to have three table. Table of users which contain all users you got message from, table of messages with fields date and users id, messages table with fields message, user, and boolean flag which mean did you send or receive. And then you can fetch all messages for certain user. And thean as you suggest sort messages on date. But I guess that list already will be sorted by date, because I think they bill be saved sorted by date. If messages too much or you gonna get them from server it would be better not load all message at once.